# Regular expression with POSIX bracket expressions not working in bash

Tags: regex, bash, posix

I have this regular expression that works in Rubular

```
value[[:space:]]*=[[[:digit:]]\.]+>([[[:alpha:]][[:space:]]*\/]+)
```

on this text:

```
<option value =12.34.567>London</option>
<option value =89.12.345>New York / San Francisco</option>
```

It gives the result:

```
Match 1
1.  12.34.567
2.  London
Match 2
1.  89.12.345
2.  New York / San Francisco
```

Which is what I want. But when i use the regular expression in a bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

regex="value[[:space:]]*=([[[:digit:]]\.]+)>([[[:alpha:]][[:space:]]*\/]+)"

while read line
do
    echo $line
    if [[ $line =~ $regex ]]; then
        echo ${BASH_REMATCH}
    fi
done < test.html
```

It doesn't work (test.html has the html sample from above.)

From testing I think it gets stuck in the grouping

```
[[[:digit:]]\.]+
```

Does bash treat the regular expressions in a different way than ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to change the regex as,

```
regex="value[[:space:]]*=([[:digit:].]+)>([[:alpha:][:space:]*/]+)"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tN2yW0/1)

```
    [[:digit:].]
    ^   ^    ^^^
    |   |    |||-> end of char class
 start digit |-> DOT
            OR
```

In pcre, the above would be written as `[\d.]`

Comment: Yes it works. But I though posix classes in bash had to have double brackets `[[:space:]]`` always

Comment: The class itself is just `[:space:]`, but it must appear inside a bracket expression, hence the other set of brackets.